# User interface problems in visual studio application after changing windows font size

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, styles

I am trying to fix a legacy application and recently found a bug. When user changes windows font size to normal 125%. All the styles just go nuts.

The solution in my mind is that I can force original size of application even in higher font and icon size settings but no idea how to do it or is there any better work around?

Comment: You don't indicate what "just go nuts" means.  However, the more appropriate way to resolve this is to support the font change.  "Older" users tend to pick a font that makes it easier to work with the software.

Comment: Actually I don't have enough repetition to post pics, "just go nuts"  means labels,button, panels etc. are overlapping and out of their positions. I think the guy who designed interface didn't left enough space for auto scaling and hard coded most of the size properties.I have to go for complete redesign here I think

Comment: Agreed.  It does not sound like the application was designed with the ability to scale fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibility that one or more fonts active on your system is causing a problem. I too use the Windows 125% setting. With VSC2013, I had strange problems using the customize-toolbar "Modify Selection" menu. When I tried to use that menu, its text would move quickly off the screen, leaving me unable to make any change.

I searched the web in vain looking for any reports of this.

However, after changing many vs2013 IDE font settings to "MS Reference Sans Serif" font, I was surprised to see that menu pop up fine -- allowing me to complete my customization. I concluded I had a misbehaving font in my Windows O/S. I did export my settings (before trying this) to ensure I could restore the IDE if needed. Now it works fine and I can code in comfort. I discovered this by accident... Perhaps its worth a try on your issue?